# Limit of multivariate function?

Tags: limits

I have a multivariate function as
$$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)=\frac{1}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i)^{\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}a_i}}\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{m}b_i^{x_i}\Big)\Big(\prod_{i=1}^mx_i^{a_i}\Big),~~~x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_m>0$$
where $a_1, \ldots, a_{m+1}$ are positive real numbers and $0<b_i<1$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots m$. I want to calculate $lim_{x_i \to \infty}f=?$. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\prod_{i=1}^mx_i^{a_i}\le x^{\sum_ia_i}$$ where $x=\min\{x_i\}$ and

$$\prod_{i=1}^{m}b_i^{x_i}\le b^{\sum_ix_i}\le b^{mx},$$ where $b=\max\{b_i\}.$

Is not $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^ab^{mx}=0$ for any positive $a?$